# Client side fetching Vue component

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm trying to fetch the component using **Vue with cdn** to dynamically re-render from the public project that has like a file **cash-sale.vue** always with **.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      "rows": 4
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="rows++">
    {{ rows }}
  </button>
</template>
```

Then in another project I have **index.html** like a web app

```
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="_app">
    <component-form></component-form>
  </div>

  <script>
    ;(async function(){
      const form = await fetch(`lite/vuejs/cash-sale.vue`).then(res => res.text())

      // need to fix
      const script = form.substring(form.indexOf(`<script>`) + 8, form.indexOf(`<\/script>`))
      const template = form.substring(form.indexOf(`<template>`) + 10, form.indexOf(`</template>`))

      const wayForData = script.indexOf(`return `)
      const data = script.substring(wayForData + 7, script.indexOf(`}`, wayForData + 8) + 1)

      const app = Vue.createApp({})

      app.component(`component-form`, {
        data(){
          return JSON.parse(data)
        },
        template,
      })
  
      app.mount(`#_app`)

    })();
  </script>
</body>
```

This works fine but I use **JS functions to cut the string** to get Vue component working.

But in reality we don't just use like this

*public project*

```
...
data(){
  return {
    "rows": 4
  },
}
...
```

---

*another project*

```
...
const wayForData = script.indexOf(`return `)
const data = script.substring(wayForData + 7, script.indexOf(`}`, wayForData + 8) + 1)
...
```

We do more than **data()** if use JS functions to cut the string will definitely be chaotic

Does Vue its self support **file.vue** that be able to **fetch** without doing un-common cutting strings like I did?

Use just client side **index.html** possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question.

Vue Single File Component files - so .vue files - are meant to be compiled by Webpack.

What you're doing with .substring is clever, but it's also prone to breaking - what if someone uses eg. this.$store in a component? The website where you use .substring won't know what to do with this.$store

Since you want to use **only** a raw file without Webpack, you have a few options:

1. Use render functions
   Use this if your component has 1-2 DOM elements. It's really painful, since you have to do eg. `{ template(h) { return h('div') } }`. The benefit here is that you can put your vue component in a simple .js file and avoid parsing the .vue file
2. Use alternate template definitions - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Alternate-Template-Definitions
   The problem here is that again - you can put the script part of .vue file in a .js file, but you'll have to redefine the template each time.

But really, try using Webpack to build your .vue files. You don't even need to publish an npm package or anything. You can just build the .umd.js file locally, copy it and drop it into your CDN then take your components out.

```html
<!-- this makes window.myVueComponents available -->
<head><script src="yourcdn.com/my-vue-components.umd.js"/></head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <cash-sale :items="myItems"/>
</div>
<script>
new Vue({
  //myVueComponents is globally available thanks to .umd.js include
  components: { CashSale: myVueComponents.CashSale },
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      myItems: ['toy','car','doll']
    }
  }
})
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, it's render(h) not template(h)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm new to use Vue. I'll learn something from your answer. I've heard about server component. Is it the same thing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: So about **.umd.js** file is [this](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) the correct document to learn?

Comment: I think it's too detailed, but you can read it if you want. Basically, UMD script = script that makes your library appear globally in JS (like the myVueComponents above). The document to read is https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library - there you have eg. dist/myLib.umd.js mentioned

But this is a guide that applies to Vue CLI - so something that applies to you if you created your app using the `vue create` command